# How to change text direction in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

When i write in both English and Persian text in LibreOffice at the usual, the order of the text is disturbed.

In Microsoft Office in windows, we have to setting about "text align" and "text direction" and in LibreOffice office i just see about "text align" and i don't see any option for text direction.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/726306/856934) answer in superuser shows you how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In LibreOffice 7  Tools -> Options... -> Language Settings -> Languages -> Default Languages for Documents -> Check on `Complex text layout` option (Also select the preferred language from the dropdown menu) -> Press Apply and OK button

Then use

`Ctrl+Shift+D` --- switch right to left entry

`Ctrl+Shift+A`--- switch left to right entry

OR

You can use Left-To-Right and Right-To-Left icons

[image: img_text_direction]

Comment: Thank you for your answering, i used shortcut keys and worked it, but i don't have the option in the picture , maybe because i haven't installed microsoft office theme!

Comment: @amir abouei  Maybe. One thing you can do, Goto Tools -> Customize... -> Toolbars tab -> Available Commands -> Look for `Left-To-Right` and `Right-To-Left` icon from the command list and add them by clicking on the `Add Item` button -> OK

Comment: Yes and i can add it by your guidance, Thank you!